# Phone number format in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to format some cells for a phone number in the form 111-111-1111. I do so as in the screenshot below. This works as far as it goes, however, it falls short in that the user can enter more than 10 digits or less than 10 digits. How to I get it to require exactly 10 digits?

[image: format cells]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate the data entered. On the menu bar, click on Data -> Validity. On the Allow box, select Text length. On the Data box, select `equal`. Enter 10 as the value.

[image]

Click on the Error Alert tab, enable "Show error message when invalid values are entered". Optionally, set a title and the error message that should be shown.

[image]

When users enter a phone number whose length is not equal to 10, a message box will be displayed.

[image]